# How do I specify what function to export from .so library, when compiling the C code?

Tags: c

I have a number of function in my "C" code. When I compile .so, I see all names in result .so file. How can I specify (in code or in make file) that only some functions should be exported, where as others are private just for internal use.

Comment: I think the .def files can be used for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, if you want a function to remain internal to the file (technically, the "compilation unit") that contains it, you declare it "static". For example,

```
static int privateAddOne(int x) { return x + 1; }
```

Comment: Private to the compilation unit and private to the library are hardly the same thing - most non-trivial libraries have many source files.

Answer (score 23):

Since you mention `.so` files, it seems like a reasonable assumption that you're using `gcc` or a gcc-alike compiler.

By default all `extern` functions are visible in the linked object.  You can hide functions (and global variables) on a case-by-case basis using the `hidden` attribute (while keeping them `extern`, which allows them to be used from other source files in the same library):

```
int __attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) foo(void)
{
    return 10;
}
```

Alternatively you can change the default to `hidden` by passing the `-fvisibility=hidden` option to `gcc` at compile time.  You can then mark particular functions for export using:

```
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

Comment: +1 Honestly this is a better answer (in that it is more powerful) than the accepted one. Of course you should be using a mix of the two!

Comment: +1 To add another option, you could use a combination of ld linker and version scripts to achieve a similar result without touching the source code.

Comment: This answer is correct, but you should never use it. Code which depends on hiding symbols with visibility to avoid polluting the namespace and breaking the calling program is inherently nonportable. If you need external functions which are not supposed to be used outside the library itself, you should simply prefix their names with some library-specific junk (but not leading underscores).

Comment: @R.: It can still be a worthwhile optimisation, even if you're properly using symbol prefixes, because it will reduce the size of the symbol table.